# Paragraph fields as node tokens in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, tokens, meta-tags

Is there a Drupal 7 equivalent to `[node:field_paragraph:0:entity:field_hero_image]`?

I'm trying to use an image field in a [paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) as the og:image using the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module, but the only token I can see is `[node:field_paragraph]` and I can't see a way to access fields in the paragraph.